# How to make negative time show up in Red in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have complicated formulas in cells and at the end, I need to show up negative hours in red color in Excel. I need to use formula, `conditional formatting` is NOT a case.

The cell A1, A3, and A4 are `Time` formatted, the used pattern is `hh:mm;@`

The formula in cell A1 is `=IF(A3-A4<0, TEXT(ABS(A3-A4),"[Red]-hh:mm"), A3-A4)`. It comes from [this](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T006239_Displaying_Negative_Times.html) article. Values sit in cells A3 and A4.

My problel is that in case of negative hours the `[Red]` keyword is not applied in cell A1.

Comment: A formula cannot change the color of the text.  You will need to use conditional formatting: `=ISTEXT(A1)` then make the text red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Highlight the data range you want formatted.
2. Under the `Home` tab select `Conditional Formatting`
3. Under `Conditional Formatting` select `Highlight Cell Rules` then `Less Than`
4. Put "0" in the input box and from the drop-down on the right select the format you want or make one. In cases where the value is negative it will be red text.

Please Note that for this to work, you need to have your cells formatted properly, so by making the result text this may not work. I would first explore the date formats and find the one that suits your needs best. From what I can see in your request, under custom format `hh:mm` should do the trick.